# Is there a DV VHF calling frequency in the UK?

Tags: vhf, united-kingdom, band-plan, d-star

On the [band plan for VHF for the UK](http://rsgb.org/main/operating/band-plans/vhf-uhf/144mhz-band/), I can see 145.500MHz being the FM calling frequency but I cannot find any for DV. Is there one?

In contrast, [for UHF](http://rsgb.org/main/operating/band-plans/vhf-uhf/432mhz-band/), I can see a calling frequency for FM at 433.500MHz and one for DV at 438.6125MHz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The D-Star simplex frequencies in the UK are 144.6125 MHz, 438.6125 MHz and 1298.6125 MHz.

Answer (score 0):

144.6125 is the calling frequency for all Digital modes.

Comment: Hey Brian, welcome to the Amateur Radio Stack Exchange. Are you new to Stack Exchange sites?